# Django: How to get Form field descriptions to show inside the text/entry box and not outside of it? (pic inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a page in my django project with many forms and it would be much more elegant of a design if the form descriptors appeared inside the entry boxes in faded gray text and disappeared as soon as the user started entering text into the box. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, but I'm guessing it's jquery/js? Is there any other built-in django ways to do this that I am not seeing? If not, what is the best way to go about doing it in js then? The pic below is what I mean. Notice how toolbars like facebook's search have the prompt text inside the entry box while my link entry form in my app is outside of the box.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PASnZ.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@artm is right, placeholder is an attribute within input tag, Django allows you to add placeholder attribute using widget, for example:

```
from django import forms

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(label='name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Please enter your name'}))
```

That will insert placeholder attribute that will give you exactly what you described.

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I was talking about. I was aware of how to do a placeholder attribute in standard bootstrap, but I was wondering how to do it internally in django since I already displayed the forms in the template using {{myform.url}} and didn't have any place to use the placeholder tags that artm suggested. This is exactly what I was wondering about. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask, is there any way to possibly add variables in the placeholder text? Such as, instead of just "Please enter your name" is there anyway to call the variable that stores someone's username and have the placeholder say something like "{{Username}}, Please enter your real name." Or does the placeholder widget not allow calling of variables inside its text?

Comment: You can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks, then you can change attributes within the template, e.g. {% render_field myform.username placeholder=Username %}.

Comment: Oh thank you! What a useful link. I didn't even know that existed.